# Hashed with bcrypt

Tags: security, hash, passwords

Hello everyone i got an email from freepik.It said my email has been accessed together with your password in an encrypted form (hashed with bcrypt).

and want me to change my password. What does it mean?

Answer (score 0):

I got same email that my email and password leaked.